# Hbase [READ-FAILED] during YCSB Benchmarking

Tags: hbase, ycsb

I am using CDH and through that insatlled HBase and downloaded YCSB Package.Now while running test on Hbase using following command :

```
ycsb run hbase10 -p columnfamily=cf -P /usr/share/ycsb/workloads/workloada -s -threads 100 -p  recordcount=5000 -p operationcount=5000
```

Its giving output as follows where near about 50% reads are failing :

```
[OVERALL], RunTime(ms), 7059.0
[OVERALL], Throughput(ops/sec), 708.3156254426973
[READ-FAILED], Operations, 938.0
[READ-FAILED], AverageLatency(us), 6417.266524520256
[READ-FAILED], MinLatency(us), 897.0
[READ-FAILED], MaxLatency(us), 157567.0
[READ-FAILED], 95thPercentileLatency(us), 18223.0
[READ-FAILED], 99thPercentileLatency(us), 45887.0
[CLEANUP], Operations, 200.0
[CLEANUP], AverageLatency(us), 1489648.93
[CLEANUP], MinLatency(us), 3.0
[CLEANUP], MaxLatency(us), 5054463.0
[CLEANUP], 95thPercentileLatency(us), 4960255.0
[CLEANUP], 99thPercentileLatency(us), 5046271.0
[READ], Operations, 1559.0
[READ], AverageLatency(us), 7588.287363694676
[READ], MinLatency(us), 970.0
[READ], MaxLatency(us), 178047.0
[READ], 95thPercentileLatency(us), 21903.0
[READ], 99thPercentileLatency(us), 59583.0
[READ], Return=OK, 1559
[READ], Return=NOT_FOUND, 938
[UPDATE], Operations, 2503.0
[UPDATE], AverageLatency(us), 13026.518977227328
[UPDATE], MinLatency(us), 2686.0
[UPDATE], MaxLatency(us), 200575.0
[UPDATE], 95thPercentileLatency(us), 33599.0
[UPDATE], 99thPercentileLatency(us), 61599.0
[UPDATE], Return=OK, 2503
```

I tried changing split_no during database creation,Also read replication factor also enabled and made 3 during table creation.

I am searching why this is happening, but no luck, Can anybody please help me to make this work ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting the same behavior with my YCSB runs. I still didn't solve this problem but maybe this might be helpful for your case:

https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/issues/639

The guy solved this by lowering the field_length value in the workload file from 255 to 250.

Comment: Thanks @salim. I will give a try to it :)

Comment: fieldlength: the size of each field (default: 100)   here it saying fieldlength is 100 by default, and I am using the core workloads only so I guess this is not issue in my case.

Comment: I finally got rid of the failed reads. The problem was that the recordcount and operationcount values were greater than the ones in the actual database so make sure that you use the same recordcount and operationcount values that you used in the load operation.

Comment: Hey @salim Now I am facing an issue,while running YCSB it works with one thread till 30K record count and operation count( beyong that it fails with 1 thread also).

I tried with multiple threads then it fails saying 0 operations/sec and my region server goes down.Even I give two threads.

Comment: Hi @Ankita I haven't a similar problem like that before. It seems like a problem from the database side though. Can you post more output info here and your database setup?